Strapi filter request findOne
I have the following query:
/api/news/5?populate[Content][populate]=*&populate[Thumbnail]=*&populate[Pdf]=*&populate[Metadata]=*&filters[Metadata][isPublic][$eq]=true&filters[Metadata][publicFrom][$lte]=2024-10-02&filters[Metadata][publicTo][$gte]=2024-10-02
but despite the fact that the article with id == 5 is not public (isPublic == false), it still returns the article.
How should I construct the query to return the correct result?
I tried to find something in the documentation, but unfortunately, I didn't find anything.
